# Android Browser application hide url

Tags: android, url, browser, hide

I am abandoning the webview version of my simplified and switching to the default browser to produce my app. I've already found that using the browser to allow video and audio sources to play with the default media player is the best working solution to my issue however the one important item I would like to implement is to have the url bar not appear. I was almost sure that the solution was to place tell my manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

but that didn't work. The only solution that I find here is stack overflow is also `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`.

Oh help me Stackoverflow Jedi Knights, you're my only hope.

```
package com.AFMoB.AlphaPlayerTester;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AlphaPlayerTester extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://myapp.com/doit"); 
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you launch the browser independently (as opposed to host a WebView), you can't control of its appearance. There might be some setExtras that can control some behavior (I do not know about that), but most probably the apps you saw are implementing a Webview instead.

**Definitely, the browser will not be modified by your manifest file, as it is an independent application**. The URI will start the default browser for each device, which only in some will be the android browser. It could be any other browser the user decided to use instead.

Comment: I am positive it exists because I have seen other applications that utilize it

Comment: Please don't mis understand, I want the URL to work, I just do not want the url to be visible to the user and believe the space should be dedicated to the interface.

Comment: @Kazuko I did understand you. But I insist in what I said.

Comment: OK - How about we draw over the URL as shown in the following program however with a box that only points back to the home page of the app and another box that points to a given search in the android market. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.techno.ashley&feature=search_result

Comment: What about in WebChromeClient ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can't do it, you can't even guarantee what browser the user will have installed.

Comment: how about if using webchromeclient?